# LearnRubyTheHardWay Ex#46 - rake aborted, you should require 'minitest/autorun'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm on Example 46 of Learn Ruby The Hard Way - Creating a Project Skeleton

Link: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex46.html

So I created all the directories which show up as the following:

```
skeleton/
    NAME.gemspec
    Rakefile
    data
    ext/
    tests/
    bin/
        NAME
    doc/
    lib/
        NAME
        NAME.rb
    lib/NAME
    tests/
        test_NAME.rb
```

I'm in the `Skeleton` directory in Powershell.

When I run `rake test` as the tutorial says to I get an error.

Here's the result from Powershell:

```
PS C:\ruby\learn\projects\skeleton> rake test
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -I"lib;tests" -I"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4
.2/lib" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/test_NAME
.rb"
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/ruby/learn/projects/skeleton/tests/test_NAME.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:
in `<module:Unit>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:676:in `<class:Runner>': undefined method `_run_suite' for class
 `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:261:in `<module:Unit>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/ruby/learn/projects/skeleton/tests/test_NAME.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block
in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'

rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib;tests" -I"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/
lib" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/test_NAME.rb
" ]

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The book says I should get the following response:

```
Loaded suite tests/test_NAME
Started
.
Finished in 0.000226 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

But instead I get an error. I've search for fixes and using `gem install minitest` but keep in mind I don't have a gemfile and I don't know if I should for this type of project. If I needed one I assume the tutorial would say so. So what do I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `Gemfile`. While you are at `skeleton` directory, just do:

```
gem install 'test-unit'
```

and then from the same directory:

```
rake test
```

All tests will pass.

*P.S. I just reproduced the whole thing locally following your tutorial and got the error message as yours. Then, I installed the `test-unit` gem and after that the `rake test` is working without any error.*